# I need help to create a program that accepts as many inputs as the user wants

Tags: arrays, c, comparison

i am trying to write a program that processes a collection of values, i need to group the values in 85+, 60-84,and less than 60, and lastly average the temperature. i know i need to use an array to store the values, i am using a do while loop to ask for the inputs. but the loop must quit when -99 is put in and im not sure if i did that right. i am also unsure if how a group the inputs is implemented correctly, and i need to print the average.

```
      #include <stdio.h>
     
      int main(void){
      //declare variables
      int num[30];
      int Cday[30];
      int Pday[30];
      int Hday[30];
      int total;
      int total_ave;
      double ave;
      int NHday, NPday, NCday;
     
     
      //ask input store into num, then decides if the number goes into which array   
      do{
              printf("Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)>");
              scanf ("%d", num);
     
              if(num<=60 && num>=0){
                  Cday = num;
                  }
              else if(num>=60 && num<=84){
                  Pday = num;
                  }
              else if(num<=84 && num>=200){
                  Hday = num;
                  }
     
      }while(num >=0);
     
      //calculating the average
      total = sizeof(num);
     
          for(int i = 0;i< total; i++){
              total_ave = total_ave +num[i];
          }
          ave = total_ave / total;
     
     
      NHday = sizeof(Hday);
      NPday = sizeof(Pday);
      NCday = sizeof(Cday);
     
     
      //printing the final statement once all the values are calculated
          printf("Hot days:\t %d\n", NHday);
          printf("Pleasant days:\t %d\n", NPday);
          printf("Cold days:\t %d\n\n", NCday);
     
          printf("The average temperature was %.2f degrees.", ave);
     
     
     
     
      //stops compiling when -99 is entered not collected as information
      //
      //
      return(0);
      }
```

I'm not sure if I'm storing the inputs correctly using arrays for the Cday Pday and Hday.

the warnings I get when using -Wall are

comparison between pointer and integer on lines 31, 34 and 37, and the other error I get is my assignment to Cday Pday and Hday. so i'm wondering what I need to change so that the code will function the way I want it to.

with the second error I am trying to place the input of the user into one of those three categories.

Comment: _//stops compiling when -99 is entered ..._ Do you mean stop executing?

Comment: yes i do mean stops executing, thank you

Comment: I suggest to remove the line numbers, so we can compile the code.

Comment: good idea, will do.

Comment: Looking at the question that you asked, you really do not need to use any arrays...

Answer (score 2):

For what I understand, you want to exit when user enters -99, to do that just check the return of `scanf` and exit the loop if the condition is met:

```
int stop = scanf("%d", &num) != 1; // scanf wants a pointer

if (stop || (num == -99))
{
    break;
}
```

Notice that `num` must be a single `int`, not an array of 30 `int`s.

And here you are misusing `sizeof`:

```
NHday = sizeof(Hday);
NPday = sizeof(Pday);
NCday = sizeof(Cday);
```

Those lines doesn't return the summary of lines entered in each section, but the size of the type in bytes, i.e:

```
NHday = sizeof(Hday) = sizeof(int) * 30 = 4 * 30 = 120
```

Not what you want, instead, use `NHday` as a counter and don't forget to initialize `NHday` to 0 in order to avoid unexpected behaviours:

```
int NHday = 0, ...;
```

Finally

```
  //calculating the average
  total = sizeof(num);
```

same problem, you don't want `sizeof`.

Your code simplified (you don't need an array):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    int NHday = 0, NPday = 0, NCday = 0, N = 0, num = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)>");
        int stop = scanf("%d", &num) != 1;

        if (stop || (num == -99))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (num > 0 && num < 60)
        {
            NCday++;
        }
        else if (num >= 60 && num <= 84)
        {
            NPday++;
        }
        else if (num > 84 && num <= 200)
        {
            NHday++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue; // Do not increase N
        }
        sum += num;
    } while (++N);

    //printing the final statement once all the values are calculated
    printf("Hot days:\t %d\n", NHday);
    printf("Pleasant days:\t %d\n", NPday);
    printf("Cold days:\t %d\n\n", NCday);

    printf("The average temperature was %.2f degrees.\n", sum / N);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the new code to compile but onthe else if section on the num<=84 i get a  warning: comparison between pointer and integer, and then on the other warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   43 |                         Pday[NPday] = num; how do i correct those?

Comment: Because you are using `num` as an array, there is an edit.

Comment: how do i fix that? how do i use the value that is inputed from the user?

Comment: Declare `int num;` instead of `int num[30];`

Comment: but dont i need the num to be an array to hold more values when there is more than one input from the user?

Comment: Edited, I didn't want to spoonfeed but there are so many problems in your code, see the basis of arrays, you can find a nice introduction in the C-FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: @Ivickt Extra: with some little tweaks in this code, you can even find out the average of each group

Comment: thank you for all the help ive only been in the class for a couple days, so i really appreciate it.

Comment: Best advise for learning C (or any language for that matter) is *Slow Down*, take it step by step, understand what you need to do before you pick up a keyboard. There is a lot to learn in C. It will take much more than a semester or two to become proficient. It's more a journey than a race, so slow down and enjoy the learning.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [ten years](https://norvig.com/21-days.html) ;)

Comment: It takes more than 24 hours to ascend the pyramid in anything [Bloom's Taxonomy of Cognitive Development](http://cehdclass.gmu.edu/ndabbagh/Resources/IDKB/bloomstax.htm) (though I usually replace "Evaluation" with "Value" `:)` They figured that out before the '57 Chevy rolled off the assembly lines....